# Discord.js sequelize.import is not a function

Tags: sequelize.js, bots, discord.js

So I followed this tutorial to a T or so I'm thinking most of the code cab be viewed on the link provided as i have never used sequelize before `https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html#file-overview`

and I can't seem to fix this error `TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function` I've fiddled around with it for a couple of hours installed all its dependencies reinstalled it etc. Tried messing with the const's to see if that was the issue nope.

error seems to be on anything sequelize.import

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

const Users = sequelize.import('models/Users');
const CurrencyShop = sequelize.import('models/CurrencyShop');
const UserItems = sequelize.import('models/UserItems');

UserItems.belongsTo(CurrencyShop, { foreignKey: 'item_id', as: 'item' });

Users.prototype.addItem = async function(item) {
    const useritem = await UserItems.findOne({
        where: { user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id },
    });

    if (useritem) {
        useritem.amount += 1;
        return useritem.save();
    }

    return UserItems.create({ user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id, amount: 1 });
};

Users.prototype.getItems = function() {
    return UserItems.findAll({
        where: { user_id: this.user_id },
        include: ['item'],
    });
};

module.exports = { Users, CurrencyShop, UserItems };
```

my package.json just in case upon googling I found something that might be the problem in here so just adding it

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "ViridianZe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "better-sqlite3": "^7.1.0",
    "bindings": "^1.5.0",
    "canvas": "^2.6.1",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "discord": "^0.8.2",
    "discord-auditlog": "^2.1.6",
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "discord.js-commando": "github:discordjs/Commando",
    "discord.js.old": "^11.6.5",
    "dottie": "^2.0.2",
    "index.js": "0.0.3",
    "inflection": "^1.12.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "nan": "^2.14.1",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.15.0",
    "npm-install-all": "^1.1.21",
    "nvm": "0.0.4",
    "nvmw": "^1.0.0",
    "prebuild-install": "^5.3.4",
    "reaction-role": "^1.7.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.2.3",
    "sequelize-pool": "^6.0.0",
    "sqlite": "^4.0.11",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0",
    "tar": "^6.0.2",
    "toposort-class": "^1.0.1",
    "uui": "^1.0.7",
    "validator": "^13.1.1",
    "wkx": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Any help or pointers would be much! appreciated! as I haven't got a clue as to what I can do to try and fix it now

Answer (score 3):

Sequelize deprecated import and now they suggest you use require. If you're following along with the Currency System in the Discord.js documentation you'll need to change the imports.

```
const CurrencyShop = sequelize.import('models/CurrencyShop');
sequelize.import('models/Users');
sequelize.import('models/UserItems');
```

becomes:

```
const CurrencyShop = require('models/CurrencyShop')(sequelize, Sequelize);
require('models/Users')(sequelize, Sequelize);
require('models/UserItems')(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

I have done something similar in my own project and it has worked quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to find a Fix-it was all down to the placement of my index.js code make sure you keep it all below the initialization regardless of what the tutorial says.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Could you clarify further please?